# angular.js - ng-disabled not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to only enable my button if the textfield have input but I can't get `ng-disabled` to work:

```
<form novalidate>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="add('+')" ng-disabled="bittext.$invalid">Done</button>   
    <textarea type="text" ng-model="bittext"  size="30" placeholder="add bittext here" style="width: 212px; height:100px" required=""></div>
</form>
```

But when I tried(without the `$invalid`)

```
<form novalidate>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="add('+')" ng-disabled="bittext">Done</button><!-- no '.$invalid'-->  
        <textarea type="text" ng-model="bittext"  size="30" placeholder="add bittext here" style="width: 212px; height:100px" required=""></div>
    </form>
```

it will disable my button when I input something in the text field.

Comment: May you show your js?

Comment: You have an extra space in   `ng-disabled="bit text.$invalid"`

Comment: Sorry, that is because of the auto-correct feature. Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try ng-disabled="!bittext" . Also in your first paste you have bit text (space). That may be why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

1. your using form so you can try like this also

   ```
   <form name="form" novalidate>
       <button type="submit" ng-click="add('+')" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Done</button>
       <textarea type="text" ng-model="bittext"  size="30" placeholder="add bittext here" style="width: 212px; height:100px" required=""></textarea>
   </form>
   ```